# Displaying Raw JSON in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I recognize that this may be a duplicate but i have not been able to find an example that gets me to where i need to go. I have recently discovered the jspdf library. I am trying to print raw JSON data into a modal so as to print it to PDF. I already have JSON coming into my page to populate a slickgrid. My question is how exactly do i get the data that is already coming in to display inside my modal as JSON stringify? Here is my [**GeneratePDF Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/bu9db10d/)

```
   $.getJSON('GetCatsforCatviews', function (data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);
        leadRequests.push(item);
    });

}).done(function (result) {
    var CatGrid;
    var CatsbycolorGrid;
</script>

    <div id="dialog-pdf" title="pdf" stye="display:none;">
    <div id="content">
        <h3>Cat Request Details</h3>

        <p>All of the Cat Details.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <a href="#" id="cmd">generate PDF</a>

</div>

$("#dialog-pdf").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    buttons: { 'close': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});


if ($(e.target).hasClass('show-pdf')) {
            var pdfDialog = $("#dialog-pdf");
            if (typeof pdfDialog === "undefined"); {
                console.log("Dialog is undefined")
                pdfDialog.dialog("open");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback to $.getJSON(), you could do the following provided result is a javascript object.

`$('#editor').text(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));`

With a change to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bu9db10d/2/

Comment: Youre the man! now it doesnt print to the pdf on my local but thats another issue. Thanks alot.